# gradle lint stuck in command line only

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio project (3.1.3)

When i run `Analyze -> Inspect Code` Lint runs for a reasonable amount of time and gives results. It lets me pick which modules to run lint on, etcetera.

When i run it using `./gradlew lint --debug` Lint runs and gets eventually stuck in a loop of the following:

`3:52:50.637 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
13:52:50.637 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:52:50.638 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:52:50.638 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
13:52:50.638 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.`

How can i get the command line to run like it does on Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to disable the gradle Daemon in the gradle config file (look "Disabling the Daemon" paragraph of [THAT](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) link to the how-to).

Now it should work, or at least it gave you the "real" error message.

Hope that help,
Legion-

P.s.: In case the link will be deleted or moved I quote the part i think you need:

> The Gradle Daemon is enabled by default, and we recommend always
>   enabling it. There are several ways to disable the Daemon, but the
>   most common one is to add the line
>
> org.gradle.daemon=false to the file
>   «USER_HOME»/.gradle/gradle.properties, where «USER_HOME» is your home
>   directory. That’s typically one of the following, depending on your
>   platform:
>
> C:\Users\ (Windows Vista & 7+)
>
> /Users/ (macOS)
>
> /home/ (Linux)
>
> If that file doesn’t exist, just create it using a text editor

Comment: Thank you. Doing this enabled me to find the right problem which was a lint issue with an old version of Timber described here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37128699

Answer (score 0):

To run the lint task for only a specific build variant, you must capitalize the variant name and prefix it with lint. [details](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#commandline)

```
./gradlew lintDebug
```